# How can I import total Ordner

Tags: python, csv, import

I have path *'/Users/OneDrive/Desktop/Data_CSV' in this path I have 3 folders in each folder 5 folders in each folder 12 csv data.*

how can i import total?

what I can. I can only import a whole folder, but folders in folders in folders I can not do well.

this code is for one Ordner:

```
import glob
import os   
import pandas as pd 

directory = '/Users/OneDrive/Desktop/Data_CSV'

all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*.csv"))



your_list = [ ]
for filename in all_files:
    dataframe = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0, sep="\t")
    your_list.append(dataframe)
    print(dataframe)
```

Comment: Hi @Sameer can you try my answer, let me know if it helps or if you have any doubts

Comment: Hi @Himanshuman, I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: what error r u getting? can you show

Comment: Hi@Himanshuman I dont get an error ,but  i get nothing

Comment: @Himanshuman... I can import a whole folder, but filesin folders in folders in folders I can not do.  I think, you didn't understand the task well, but you can do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the folders recursively

```
import glob

# root_dir needs a trailing slash (i.e. /root/dir/)
for filename in glob.iglob(directory + '**/*.txt', recursive=True):
     dataframe = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0, sep="\t")
     your_list.append(dataframe)
```